# Python User Defined Function in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to figure out xlwings.  I have the following python code:

```
from xlwings import xlfunc
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

@xlfunc
def convert(gmt):

    gmtValue = datetime(int(gmt[6:10]), int(gmt[3:5]), int(gmt[0:2]), int(gmt[11:13]), int(gmt[14:16]), int(gmt[17:19]))
    localTime = gmtValue - timedelta(seconds=(6*3600))
    return localTime
```

All it does is take a time stamp string such as 05/01/2016 14:25:56 GMT and pulls off the GMT and converts it into local time (central time for the US.)  I'm trying to use that code along with:

```
Sub convertToLocal()
    RunPython(“import converToLocal; convertToLocal.convert(gmt)”)
End Sub
```

To make a user defined function but Excel doesn't seem to recognize the python code even though I have the xlwings.bas module imported.  The only error I get is “Compile error: Expected end of Statement.”  Which I think just means Excel doesn't recognize the python code.  Any idea how to fix it?  Also, what is the correct way to pass the contents of a cell into the python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RunPython` and the decorator syntax are two different approaches. To do user defined functions with decorators, follow the guide [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/udfs.html#udfs). You ll need to import those function with the add-in, no `RunPython` needed.

Comment: Now I'm getting a "runtime error '53':  File not found xlwings32.dll." When I run ImportPythonUDFs.  I checked in the folder C:\Anaconda3 and it's not there, just xlwings64.dll.  I tried "conda uninstall xlwings" and then reinstalling but the 32 still isn't there.

Comment: You're right, there seems to be an issue with the latest conda package. Please just install it with pip until this is fixed with the conda package.

Comment: Thanks!!  That did it.  Or at least the error I'm getting now has to do with astimezone() and nothing to do with xlwings as I'm getting it in a Excel cell.

Comment: Apparently, conda packages are now also fixed, use: `conda update xlwings`